# Honeysql - Clojure - How to pass a vector as arguments into Values in insert-into statement

Tags: mysql, clojure, honeysql

I'm working with Clojure using honeySql for formatting SQL statements.
The statement will run on a MySQL DB.

I'm looking for a way to pass an argument in the params and use it as the values in the inset-inro statement.

This is the statement I'm looking for :

```
INSERT INTO some_table
(a, b, c)
VALUES (1, 2, 3),
       (4, 5, 6);
```

insert attempt:

```
(def insert-demo
  (-> (insert-into :some_table)
      (columns :a :b :c)
      (values [:param :vals)))
```

This is the way I'm calling to the format function:

```
(sql/format dbcst/insert-demo {:inline true
                               :pretty true
                               :params {:vals [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]}})
```

Unforentualy this won't work.

I tried a few options in the values section no success so far.

```
(values [:?vals])

(values :?vals)
```

Is there a way to pass a vector and use it as a param?

To be clear: I'm looking for a way to pass values dynamically.

Thanks

Comment: Unless you have a good reason not to do that, you should pass the values directly into `values`, as in `(values [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]])`, just as in the example here: https://github.com/seancorfield/honeysql#inserts. You don't have to worry about escaping anything.

Comment: Thanks, it's kind of missing the point - I want to pass values dynamically

Comment: If the goal is about operating multi-insert, why wouldn't plain next.jdbc function like this(https://cljdoc.org/d/seancorfield/next.jdbc/1.2.659/api/next.jdbc.sql#insert-multi!) work? You can pass any symbol dynamically in 'rows' part without having to use honeysql syntax.

Comment: I did use it eventually - looking for another way with honeysql

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by "dynamically" - nothing is static about HoneySQL. The HoneySQL structure is created at run time - you can use any function you want to create the data. If all you want is to move the process of value binding from where you create the SQL map to where you format it, all you have to do is wrap the code that creates the SQL map in a function and call that function right before you call `sql/format`. If that's not possible, you can call all relevant HoneySQL functions except for `values` in advance, and only call `values` right before `sql/format`.

Comment: Thanks, sure it's a possible solution. I thought there might be another way supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
(def insert-demo
  (-> (insert-into :some_table)
      (columns :a :b :c)
      (values [[1 2 3] 
               [4 5 6]])))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).